# SBT plugin: add resources to resulting jar?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing an SBT plugin. In this plugin, I need to add files to the resources directory within the resulting jar.

I don't want to change anything from the source directory (otherwise the user/developer may not understand why files appear to directory he's responsible for), but only in the generated jar.

How can I do that, is there a folder in target that correspond to the resource directory?

It seems like this is done by the "package" command, so if I can override the package command I might be able to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need to add stuff to resourceManaged.